# MVC Entity Framework application connects with azure database not working with local database

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I have a simple web application developed in ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework (code-first). It was working with azure database. For development purpose I imported the data to new database on my local SQL Server, and updated the connection string. The connection is not opening for local database and throwing error

> ((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)db.Database.Connection).ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

If I run `xp_readerrorlog` from local database server, it shows

> Login failed for user '\MININT-I7JMD1C$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

Azure database connection:

```
<add name="MyAppContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=test.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=mydb1;User ID=***;Password=***;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Local DB connection:

```
<add name="MyAppContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test-db1;User ID=***;Password=***" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It works with Azure db connection, but not working with local db connection. But local db is working with SSMS and normal ado.net db connection

Can anyone see what is the issue, or anybody faced same issue?

Comment: which sql database you using

Comment: MS SQL Server 2017

Comment: are u able to connect server thought Sql management studio ? if you can then replace the server name with name from sql server instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your connection string source name not given properly, trying to change data source as

```
<add name="MyAppContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb);Initial Catalog=test-db1;User ID=***;Password=***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

or

```
<add name="MyAppContext" connectionString="Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test-db1;User ID=***;Password=***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```